# How to Start a Thin Socket-Backed Cluster from Foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin, foreman

I'm trying to set up [Discourse](http://discourse.org) behind an [Nginx](http://nginx.org) proxy, served via [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) and started via [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman).

So I have a `Procfile` like so:

```
web: thin start -p $PORT --socket tmp/sockets/thin.sock
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -e $RAILS_ENV
clockwork: bundle exec clockwork config/clock.rb
```

And a nginx `conf` file that points to the socket:

```
upstream discourse {
  server unix:///var/www/discourse/tmp/sockets/thin.sock;
}
```

And that all works great… as long as I only ever want one web worker, connected to the socket. If I were just running `thin` myself, I could tack in a `-s4` and get four thin workers, and it even handles the socket files, creating `thin.0.socket`, `thin.1.socket`, etc. But running `thin` that way spins up the workers in their own processes, and then quits, so if I put `-s4` into my `Procfile`, `foreman` thinks something died and cascades, bringing itself down, too.

Just telling `foreman start -c web=2` brings up two processes... but they both point to the same `sock` file and neither seems to work.

I'm sure there's a simple way to handle this, but I can't seem to figure out the magic incantation. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you use a TCP socket instead of a unix socket?

Comment: How about adding multiple `web` procs to the Procfile? Heroku does this where you can add a `web.1` for a web process and `worker.1` for worker processes. So, may be, you can do: `web.1: thin start ... /thin.0.sock`, `web.2: thin start ... /thin.1.sock` etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this worked:

```
# Procfile
web: thin start -p 9292 --socket /tmp/thin.0.sock
web: thin start -p 9293 --socket /tmp/thin.1.sock
web: thin start -p 9294 --socket /tmp/thin.2.sock
# and so on
```

and

```
# nginx.conf
upstream backend {
  server unix:/tmp/thin.0.sock
  server unix:/tmp/thin.1.sock
  server unix:/tmp/thin.2.sock
}
```

[edit] I don't think the port option is required when using unix sockets.

---

[edit 2] Okay, after I tested this yesterday, I started reading more about the subject of thin, unix sockets and nginx and found this blog: http://jordanhollinger.com/2011/04/22/threaded-thin-is-really-really-slow-on-ruby-1-9-2/. Lots or resources about this. Adding that here as it may help people looking for it.

---

Comment: This solution works but you cannot use the --one-by-one option to do zero-downtime restarts, right ?